# How to get all ones or all zeros from boolean result?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I (stupidly) thought if I took the boolean result of true, cast to an int and left-shifted it I would end up with the LSB repeated at every bit, obviously not!

If I had a boolean result and I wanted to convert this to all ones for true and all zeros for false, what would be the cheapest way (computationally) to do this?

```
bool result = x == y;

unsigned int x = 0;

//x becomes all ones when result is true
//x becomes all zeros when result is false
```

Comment: If you want to turn it into all ones or all zeros just use and and or operations

Comment: `I (stupidly) thought if I took the boolean result of true, cast to an int and left-shifted it I would end up with the LSB repeated at every bit` What on earth?!

Comment: It might have worked (non-portably) if you had right-shifted it as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this, perhaps:

```
bool result = x == y;

unsigned int z = -result;
```

Comment: And of course wrap it in a well-named function because this code is obscure. And add a comment as well.

Comment: [Live demo for good measure](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6e34f915a878a23)

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: Nevermind, I see. 1 * -1 = -1 which underflows to all 1s and 0 stays 0.

Answer (score 7):

A solution that is more readable IMO:

```
unsigned int set_or_unset_all_bits(bool comp) {
    return comp ? ~0u : 0;
}
```

Comment: And more correct, as it doesn't assume twos-complement representation of negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
#include <limits>
#include <stdint.h>

...

uint32_t x, y;

// init x and y with some values

if(x == y) {
  // all bits to 1
  x = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
} else {
  // all bits to 0
  x = 0;  
}
```

Comment: `int`'s max is not all ones though

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc you are right, changed to use unsigned.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, it is :)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
int main()
{
      unsigned int x, y;
      bool b = x == y;
      x = b ? std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() : 0;
}
```